# Delete Row If Cells Do Not Contain Values

Tags: vba, excel

I want to pass all cells in a certain range in column O and to delete all rows that do not contain values: OI and SI.

My code shows me an error at:

```
If Selection.Value <> "SI" Or "OI" Then
```

as a type mismatch

```
Sub CHECK()
Dim MFG_wb As Workbook
Dim Dep As Integer
Dim I As Integer

Set MFG_wb = Workbooks.Open _
("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\MFG Daily\Fast Daily " & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy") & ".xlsx", _
UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Activate

Dep = MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown)).Count

Range("O2").Select

For I = 1 To Dep

    If Selection.Value <> "SI" Or "OI" Then
        EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If

Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: add more Information: How does it not work? does it throw an error, or does it not do what you want? also which Office Version are you using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA delete rows based on multiple column criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858316/excel-vba-delete-rows-based-on-multiple-column-criteria)

Comment: @RealCheeseLord It showe me an error at: If Selection.Value <> "SI" Or "OI" Then as a type mismatch

Answer (score 5):

Try this code to solve your problem. It not only fixes the problematic line, but it avoids some other pitfalls as well that will inevitably cause issues in the long run.

```
Sub CHECK()
    Dim ManufacturingFile As Workbook
    Set ManufacturingFile = Workbooks.Open _
                 ("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\MFG Daily\Fast Daily " & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy") & ".xlsx", _
                  UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)

    Dim Aleris As Worksheet
    Set Aleris = ManufacturingFile.Worksheets("Aleris")

    Dim TotalRows As Long
    TotalRows = Aleris.Range("O2", Aleris.Range("O2").End(xlDown)).Count

    ' Avoid Select at all costs
    ' Range("O2").Select

    Dim i As Long
    For i = TotalRows To 1 Step -1
        If Aleris.Range("O" & i).Value <> "SI" And Aleris.Range("O" & i).Value <> "OI" Then
            Aleris.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

First, your issue was caused by `If Selection.Value <> "SI" Or "OI" Then` because `"OI"` cannot be evaluated as a `Boolean` statement. Behind the scenes, the interpreter tried to convert `"OI"` to `True` or `False` but was unable to. As a result, you get an error. The fix is simple:

`If Selection.Value <> "SI" or Selection.Value <> "OI" Then`. Now we have two `Boolean` statements, both checking for equality. The interpreter is happy with this and can run just fine.

Beyond this, I fixed your unqualified range references, and your practice of `Activate` and `Select`. Despite some of the suggestions from others, both of these are **very** bad habits. Your code **will** break, and it **will** cost you. Don't believe me? Read pretty much any other post about `Activate` and `Select` and you'll see the same thing.

Why is this a bad idea? You have absolutely no control over what the `ActiveSheet` is during run-time. Sure you can `Activate` it, but there will be that time where something comes in and changes the focus to another sheet, and then you'll have issues. This one bug can literally cost hours of work if you're not careful.

The fix is simple. Just declare a variable (as you almost had), and use that variable. Voila! No more worrying about having the wrong sheet.

Finally, `Excel` is really good at understanding what you mean when you use indices to reference parts of the sheet. You don't have to `Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select` and then `Selection.EntireRow.Delete` since all this really means is `ActiveSheet.Rows(Selection.Row + 1).Delete` and we can refactor that further to use a worksheet, and an index to `Foo.Rows(i + 1).Delete`. See the pattern here? Become more abstract, step by step, until your code becomes solid.

The last thing I changed was your variable names. Use descriptive names, it makes your code easier to maintain. Also, **never ever** use underscores "_" in names until you understand `Interfaces`. Underscores have special meaning to the interpreter.

Finally, check out the Rubberduck project : rubberduckvba.com. It is a free add-in that is dedicated to improving the VBA coding experience. The best part? Most of this feedback is built into RD as inspections. It does the work for you, and you get to learn in the process.

Best of luck!

Comment: `If Selection.Value <> "SI" or Selection.Value <> "OI" Then` will always evaluate to `True`. If `.Value = "OI"` then, by default, `.Value <> "SI"` is `True` (and vice-versa). It needs to be `If Selection.Value <> "SI" AND Selection.Value <> "OI" Then`.

Comment: Good catch. I knew something looked off with that, but I didnt think it through on my end :).

Answer (score 3):

As Luuklag mentioned, start at the bottom. Also best get the xlLastCell (does not stop at blank cell) to count the rows and adjust the if statement to check for both SI and OI:

```
Dep = MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Range("O2").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row


For I = Dep To 2 Step -1
    Cells(I, 15).Select
    If Not (Selection.Value = "SI" Or Selection.Value = "OI") Then
        Rows(I).Delete
    End If
Next I
```

Comment: Works perfect, Thank you!

Comment: It does the work, but after few loops it stops and writes "delete method of range class failed"

Comment: Maybe your sheet contains a table with a header and it should be skipped, I did not think of that, if so just count back to the second row: 
     For I = Dep To 2 Step -1
Also the comments on best practices by Brandon Barney are very valid (not using selection, activate, etc..)

Answer (score 2):

Individual deleting row is slow.(This delete row many times, so it takes a long time to delete)
After merge range, delete merged range at once.(use Union method)

```
Sub CHECK()
Dim MFG_wb As Workbook
Dim Dep As Long
Dim i As Long '<~~  if your data is large then use long
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim s As String
Dim rngU As Range


    Set MFG_wb = Workbooks.Open _
    ("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\MFG Daily\Fast Daily " & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy") & ".xlsx", _
    UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
    'MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Activate

    Set Ws = MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris") '<~~ instead activate, use variable
    With Ws
        Dep = .Range("O2").End(xlDown).Row
    'Range("O2").Select '<~~ select mothod is not goo.
        For i = 2 To Dep
            s = .Range("o" & i)
            If s = "SI" Or s = "OI" Then
            Else
                If rngU Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngU = .Range("o" & i)
                Else
                    Set rngU = Union(rngU, .Range("o" & i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rngU.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
MFG_wb.Save
MFG_wb.Close (0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Delete Method of range class failed for "rngU.Entireow.Delete

Comment: @RafaelOsipov,  Because of adding  "If rngU Is Nothing Then
    Else" , it should not failed.

Answer (score 1):

Once you activated sheet with `MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Activate` you don't need to explicitly use it with `Range` objects. After mentioned line, the code should look like:

```
Dim s As Sheet
Set s = MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris")
'determine last row in O column
Dep = s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 1 To Dep Step -1
    If InStr(1, s.Cells(I, 15).Value, "SI") + InStr(1, s.Cells(I, 15).Value, "OI") = 0  Then
        s.Cells(I, 15).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next I
```

Main reason for the change in a code you posted is that you are using `Select` method, which isn't a good practice. If you'd be interested, I advise you read why you should avoid using such funtions.

Comment: When deleting rows best practice is to start at the bottom and work upwards. In that way you don't need your `I = I - 1`. To do so change `For I = 1 to Dep` into: `For I = 1 To Dep Step -1`

Comment: It is even better to completely avoid Activate, and to keep a reference to the sheet.

Comment: you misunderstood me, I wnt to leave the rows with "SI" or "OI", delete the others.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov, then your question wasn't written clear enough.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn - now it does nothing, not deleting and ending the sub as is.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Try not. Also make sure that you have any rows without `SI` and `OI`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn It is actually a really bad practice to use the `Activate` command at all, and this is compounded by your recommendation for Rafael to use unqualified `Range` and `Cells` references. This is a terrible idea. The simplest example is, what if another sheet gets activated in the process of the code running? Hint: You're no longer working with the sheet you thought you were working with. You should **always** fully qualify your range references using variables that point to the object you intend to work with.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn - Just in case you weren't sure, best case is the process stops working. In this example, worst case is that you're deleting data from the _wrong worksheet_.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Fixed the code accordingly to the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Just fix line
`If Selection.Value <> "SI" Or "OI" Then`
To
`If Selection.Value <> "SI" Or Selection.Value<>"OI" Then`

Comment: Make sure you add spacing in `Selection.Value<>"OI"`. Otherwise spot on. This is the issue that should be throwing that error :).